# Why does importing Pytorch in Sublime Text cause a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pytorch

The command 'import torch' causes the build error: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch''.

But when I run the command in the terminal, pytorch works just fine (Python 3.7.X).

Comment: In Pycharm, for example, you need to add the module to the project even though you may have it installed and the terminal can run it. May it be something similar in Sublime Text? Something related to `venv`?

Comment: The `Python.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime executes `python`, which on some systems is actually Python 2 and not Python 3. So one potential problem may be that Sublime is executing a different version of Python than you think it is.

Comment: I'm already running a new package called python3..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `venv`in the project you are right now? If that is so, then you need to install torch in that `venv`, as it has been created just for the project, so it has not got any extra modules like that one.

Take a look at [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-a-Python-module-and-open-it-on-Sublime). And make sure that the module is in the environment your project is!

In Pycharm for example, whenever you create a new project with a new `venv`(virtual environment), you need to add to your `project settings->interpreter settings` the module manually, so it can be imported. Because it may be installed in your system, but not in that `venv`specifically, which will look in there!

Comment: thanks for your support. I'm not running a virtual environment - or at least not knowingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
[link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-a-Python-module-and-open-it-on-Sublime)
 it might help.
Also Faced similar issue in Windows 10 with Anaconda installed. Installed pytorch package using conda install command which I found here: http://pytorch.org/

The usual import from command-line worked for my environment(torch):

Comment: successfully attempted the install command as it said 'solving environment: done'. Unfortunately, it did not solve my ModuleError.